# I have 2 href if i click on one href it should display the selected href in bold while the other is unbold

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 href and one button if i click on one of the href the result should be the same page with selected href in bold other one in unbold.
If i click on the button i want the first href as bold. i just wrote one simple href which is similar to my problem.

```html
<a href="#" class="newUserDaily" style="color:black">New User Daily</a> |
<a href="#" class="newUserMonthly" style="color:black">New User Monthly</a><br /><br />

<input id="btnSearchNow" value="Search" type="button" />
```

Comment: You forgot to include your attempted JS code in the question

Comment: Also it's `<br/>` not `</br>`

Comment: So what do you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
     $('a').css('font-weight','');
     $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
});

$('#btnSearchNow').click(function(){
     $('a').css('font-weight','');
     $('.newUserDaily').css('font-weight','bold');
});
```

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8tny17k5/)**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it should be `anchor or a` rather than `href` that you want to highlight. As you have not provided your script, I have come up with my own version for it. Here it is:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    $('a').removeAttr('style');
    $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
});

$('#btnSearchNow').on('click', function(e){
    $('a').removeAttr('style');
    $('a:first').css('font-weight','bold');
})
```

The fiddle is given below:

https://jsfiddle.net/aalok/dhs9exue/

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code a little bit. It is an easy answer. Here you are :-

```js
function bold(id1, id2) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    document.getElementById(id1).style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    document.getElementById(id2).style.fontWeight = 'normal';
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="newUserDaily" style="color:black" onclick="bold('link1','link2')">
  <p id="link1">New User Daily</p>
</a> |
<a href="#" class="newUserMonthly" style="color:black" onclick="bold('link2','link1')">
  <p id="link2">New User Monthly</p>
</a>
<br/><br/>
<input id="btnSearchNow" value="Search" type="button" onclick="bold('link1','link2')" />
```